# Spark read delta table, getting NoSuchObjectException(message:There is no database named delta) error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Reading delta format data using spark

```
 spark.sql("select * from delta.`/mnt/data/test`").createOrReplaceTempView("test")
```

`test` view creates in spark program and I can use this view in joining. Program works fine. I can get the count of view

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from test").show(false)
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|551     |
+--------+
```

But I am also getting below error logs

```
21/08/14 13:55:52 ERROR RetryingHMSHandler: NoSuchObjectException(message:There is no database named delta)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMDatabase(ObjectStore.java:487)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:498)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:108)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_database(HiveMetaStore.java:796)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.get_database(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getDatabase(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:949)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1165)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.databaseExists(Hive.java:1154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:412)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:412)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:412)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:331)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$retryLocked$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:239)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$retryLocked$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.synchronizeOnObject(HiveClientImpl.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:314)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:411)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$withClient$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveExternalCatalog$$maybeSynchronized(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$withClient$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:142)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:372)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:358)
at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.databaseExists(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.databaseExists(SessionCatalog.scala:265)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.isRunningDirectlyOnFiles(Analyzer.scala:767)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:692)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:730)
```

I don't know why this logs are getting? How to get rid of it?
platform :  Azure Databricks
Databricks Runtime Version: 6.4 Extended support
Thanks

Comment: are you using Azure Databricks or Synapse/HDInsights/something else?

Comment: Azure Databricks

Comment: @lucy Were you able to solve this? I am facing similar issue.